# VB.NET Datatable.Select expression

Tags: vb.net, linq, select, datatable

is it possible to use filter expression to select some columns?
something like `select a,b,c from table` in sql

here is what i am trying to do

```
 Dim rows() As DataRow = bookedorders.Select("a,b,c")   'select columns a b c only, i know its wrong
        Dim zzz As DataTable = rows.CopyToDataTable
```

so is it possible to use the Datatable.Select to select columns and the use a condition like sql `WHERE a=1`

my linq try was

```
Dim q = From r In bookedorders.AsEnumerable Select r.Field(Of Integer)("a") And r.Field(Of String)("b") And r.Field(Of String)("c") And r.Field(Of Integer)("d")
        For Each m In q
            zzz.Rows.Add(m)
        Next
```

which doesnt seem to work, it says that the number of items in array is longer than the datatable!

Comment: My knowledge of VB.NET LINQ has rusted a bit, sorry for not providing the right LINQ syntax from the first time. Check my answer - here is how you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) allows you to specify a filter as a `String`:

```
bookedorders.Select("a = 1")
```

You cannot specify columns to be extracted because that would break type structure, as it is expected to return same `DataRow` as you originally had. If you were to return only specific columns, you would need another `DataTable` to contain them.

Assuming this functionality existed, limiting number of returned columns is not practical, because you already have your `DataRow`s filled with data, unlike `select a,b,c from table`, where you can reduce network bandwidth and speed up query performance by specifying only certain columns to be extracted from a database.

If you want to use LINQ, you can do it like this:

```
From r In bookedorders Select a=r.Field(Of Integer)("a"), b=r.Field(Of String)("b"), c=r.Field(Of String)("c"), d=r.Field(Of Integer)("d")
```

Note that you cannot use results of this query to directly `.Add` rows to a `DataTable`, because returned enumeration is not of type `DataRow`. If you need it badly, here is [an implementation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx).